# How to select json data randomly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have following json file and I need a way to randomly select json data and prints its value.

**json file :**

```
{
    "base": [{"1": "add"},{"2": "act"}],
    "past": [{"add": "added"},{"act": "acted"}],
    "past-participle": [{"add": "added"},{"act": "acted"}],
    "s-es-ies": [{"add": "adds"},{"act": "acts"}],
    "ing": [{"add": "adding"},{"act": "acting"}]
}
```

**example**

```
user_input = 'past' >> past
code randomly selects 'add' or 'act' from past >> add
prints out its value >> added
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `random.choice` supplying as choices the sequence contained for the selected `key`:

```
user_input = input('> ')

> past

list(choice(j[user_input]).values())[0]
Out[177]: 'added'
```

Factor it in a function to make it more compact:

```
def random_json_val(json_obj, k):
    return list(choice(json_obj[k]).values())[0]
```

Calling it gets you a random value for a given `k`:

```
>>> random_json_val(j, 'past')
'added'
>>> random_json_val(j, 'past')
'acted'
>>> random_json_val(j, 's-es-ies')
'acts'
```

Comment: it should be `list(random.choice(json_obj[k]).values())[0]`

Comment: @Scott sorry, was cooking. Yes mixed the typo, just `load` the `json` object wherever you require then pass it to the function along with the user input on which key to use.